# Autocomplete not working in the Flex Bundle for Textmate. How do I fix?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, ide, textmate

I am being very hard headed and determined that I am going to give Textmate a solid try for my actionscript and flex projects. Work on the bundle has been a little lacking but what has been developed so far is pretty great.

I have run into some slight issues but able to figure them out and get things set up pretty well and I have already dug in and started customizing the snippets to suit my needs.

One thing that I have not been able to fix, figure out or find a straight answer for is regarding working with MXML files. AutoComplete for Actionscript files seems to work great but I don't seem to get the same result when I am editing Actionscript inside the script block in a MXML file.

I am hoping that someone that uses Textmate all the time could through some suggestions my way to help track down the issue. If I am in the actionscript code block and hit (option + esc) I get "no completion available" message.

Answer (score 1):

So I posted this "issue" on the textmate mailing list and I heard back from the creator of the flex bundle. Simon basically told me that he had not enabled autocomplete feature to the flex mxml script blocks yet. This is good to know that my shit wasn't broke and he offered the following solution so that auto complete will work in mxml script blocks.

> There's no issues, I just haven't got
>   around to supporting autocompletion
>   from within script blocks embedded in
>   mxml. Although it seems to be pretty
>   stable if you just go ahead and add
>   the right scope (text.xml.mxml
>   source.actionscript.3.embedded.mxml)
>   to the command, as I have done in my
>   dev branch:
>
> http://github.com/simongregory/actionscript3-tmbundle/blob/sg/Commands/Auto%20Complete.tmCommand
>
> You can do the same thing with the
>   auto import command and it'll add the
>   import to the script block.
>
> Cheers, Simon